# Python Pickle versus Stringify

Tags: python, performance, redis, pickle

Currently I'm stringifying my dictionary with `str()` and then storing it in redis. When I want to modify the object, I get it from redis and use `eval()`. I saw that it's also possible to use the pickle module to do the same. Which is more efficient or which is better practice?

```
obj = # very large and deeply nested dictionary
cache = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
cache.set('id', str(obj))
cache.get('id')
```

or

```
obj = # very large and deeply nested dictionary
cache = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
cache.set('id', pickle.dumps(obj))
pickle.loads(cache.get('id'))
```

Comment: Why not using json.dumps? Why not use dict since redis support it?

Comment: @vishes_shell redis supports nested dictionaries? oh didn't know that.

Comment: It depends on what your consumer is doing, doesn't it? I'd recommend JSON with no other info, but ... it depends.

Comment: @Soubriquet i'm sorry, i think it don't support nested ones. Look at https://redis.io/topics/data-types

Comment: @vishes_shell i just tried and it does support nested dictionaries. also just tried using `json.loads("{'nest': {'hello': 'world'}, 'losses': [], 'pid': 0, 'val': [0.0]}")` and I got `ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`. However, `eval()` has no problem with converting that to a dict.

Comment: @Soubriquet because you dump it wrong, be careful with `eval` since it's _evil_

Comment: @vishes_shell is the json formatted incorrectly? not sure why that doesn't work.

Comment: @vishes_shell nvm I had to `json.dumps()` first. can't directly give `json.loads()` a string

Comment: @Soubriquet because valid json is with `"` and not `'`, so valid dumped json is `'{"nest": {"hello": "world"}, "losses": [], "pid": 0, "val": [0.0]}'`

Comment: There is absolutely no guarantee that `eval(str(obj)) == obj` and usually it is not. And that is the least problematic part of the idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using nested dictionaries, and redis support only

> Redis Hashes are maps between string fields and string values

Then easiest way to use `json` module

```
import json

your_dict = {}
json.dumps(your_dict)

# and to load it
your_dict_in_str = '{}'
json.loads(your_dict_in_str)
```

And try to avoid using `eval`